# What should I put down for "Reason for refusal"?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, study, applications

I'm applying for a Tier 4 (General) student visa to the UK but around last year June, I had a visit visa refused. On the letter, it says "I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 and V4.3" to then further document the reasons which include:

- Lack of evidence regarding the immigration status of the people I am intending to stay with, in the UK.
- They are not satisfied that my sponsors are legally present in the UK at the time of my proposed visit. The application has been refused under paragraph V4.3(b).
- Lack of proof of being a student at my high school at that time.
- No invitation from my UK sponsor.
- Lack of proof of how I am supported in my home country and lack of proof of family ties.
- They are not satisfied that I have strong family and financial to my home country.
- They are not satisfied that I am genuinely seeking entry as a visitor for a limited period as required by Appendix V 4.2 (a) and (c) of the Immigration Rules.

The reason for refusal field asks for a short description, but I don't know what to put in. On top of that, should I include the refusal letter too alongside all my other documents?

Comment: Would you be interested in studying in any other countries?

Comment: @SensualLettuce - what Harper is suggesting is that the likelihood of your student visa being approved after a tourist visa denial is very low. They may see you as trying to game the system and enter the country under any means possible.

Comment: @Harper I forgot to add that a few weeks later after the rejection, I did make another application after the refusal and submitted the documentation that they asked for and got accepted soon after and traveled off to the UK for the visit. I don't think It should be a problem.

Comment: Ok well if shortly after your refusal they did accept you with more documentation,  that sounds ok. The death spiral I am worried about is serial refusals.

Answer (score 10):

**Reasons for Refusal:**

*My refusal letter suggested that I was unable to satisfy the ECO that I met the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 and V4.3 of Immigration Rules Appendix V*.

They know what it means to be refused under those sections and that much detail is enough, rest of the information is redundant. There is no need to state individual reasons that you think caused your refusal.

And there is no need to include the refusal letter unless specifically asked to. It’s the same country they will have all the records based on your reference.